# How to push Ext.Panel when row selected on Ext.List in Sencha Touch 2.0?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Given a simple Ext.List like the one in the Sencha docs, how can I make a new Panel or Carousel get "pushed" onto the screen when I click on one of the names?

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/list

I'd like to be able to have a button to navigate back to the main screen too.

Comment: You need to add the select listener to the list object, then in the listener function you can figure out what record was clicked and do your calls to action... you should look at the jog with friends app to see how to properly utilize views in the new class system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Ext.navigation.View](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View). Here is a very simple application demonstrating this:

```
Ext.setup({
    // onReady is when we can start building our application
    onReady: function() {
        // Create the view by just adding a config block into Ext.Viewport.
        // We give it a reference of `view` so we can use it later
        var view = Ext.Viewport.add({
            // Give it an xtype of `navigationview` so it knows to create a NavigaitonView
            xtype: 'navigationview',

            // Define the list as its only item
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',

                    // Give it a title so the navigation view will show it
                    title: 'List',

                    // `itemTpl` is the template for each item in the list. We are going to create a store
                    // with a bunch of records, which each have a field called `name`, so we use that in our
                    // template
                    itemTpl: '{name}',

                    // Define our store
                    store: {
                        // Define the fields that our store will have
                        fields: ['name'],

                        // And give it some data for each record.
                        data: [
                            { name: 'one' },
                            { name: 'two' },
                            { name: 'three' }
                        ]
                    },

                    // Now we add a listener for the `itemtap` event, which is fired when a user taps on an item
                    // in this list. This event is passed various arguments in the signature, but we only need the
                    // record
                    listeners: {
                        itemtap: function(list, index, target, record) {
                            // now we have the record from the store, which was tapped. we now want to push a new view into
                            // the navigaitonview
                            view.push({
                                // Give it an xtype of panel
                                xtype: 'panel',

                                // Set the title to the name field of the record
                                title: record.get('name'),

                                // And add some random html
                                html: 'This is my pushed view!'
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

I've added inline comments so you know what is going on.

I also suggest you to ask questions over on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums) as you will probably receive a much quicker response.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fixes. I was half asleep while writing this. :)