# Sencha Touch 2.3.1 - onTap() record parameter returns empty object

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a simple Sencha App that has a main view. The view extends the `Ext.navigation.View` so that I can "push" to a new view when the user selects an item in the list. This happens by setting up a listener and then calling the push function on the MainView object.

However, I'm having problems getting the data across to that view. I tried using the answer from **[this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181831/how-to-push-ext-panel-when-row-selected-on-ext-list-in-sencha-touch-2-0)**, but it didn't work.

In that answer it suggests that you use the `record` parameter of the `itemTap()` function, but this returns as an empty object.

**Why does `record` return as an empty object?**

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

In my case, I have a list of "brands", each with a title, image and description. I'd like to use that in the panel that slides in.

**The launch function of my app which creates the view and ads to the viewport**

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Create instance of the main view so we can use it's functions
    SenchaTest.MainView = Ext.create('SenchaTest.view.Main');

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(SenchaTest.MainView);
},
```

**Here is my view**

```
Ext.define('SenchaTest.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Video',
        'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
        'Ext.Img'
    ],

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,

        items: [
            {
              title: 'Test',

              layout: {
                  type: 'vbox',
                  align: 'stretch'
              },

              items: [{
                xtype: 'highlightscarousel',
                flex: 0.35
              }, {
                xtype: 'list',
                displayField: 'title',
                flex: 0.65,

                store: Ext.create('SenchaTest.store.Brands'),
                itemTpl: '<img src="{image}" class="listThumb"><h1 class="listTitle">{name}</h1><span class="clearFloat"></span>',

                listeners: {
                  itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post, record) {

                  }
                }
              }]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Sencha Touch docs, the signature of the itemtap listener is:

```
(this, index, target, record, e, eOpts)
```

you're using:

```
(nestedList, list, index, element, post, record)
```

so that might be why the record is an empty object.  If that's not the case, could you post a JSFiddle or some kind of working example of the problem?